# Bridge NIC to VM without it being used by Host-machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware-workstation, network-adapter

I would like to bridge some network cards so that my virtual machines, running in VMware workstation 9, can connect through them, but not the physical windows computer on which the VM's are running. How do I do that?

I want one NIC to connect the host machine to the internet, and the rest of the NIC's to connect the VM's to the lab network.

Right now my host machine loses internet connection the second I connect any of the bridged NIC's to the lab network. Also, port security keeps seeing two MAC-addresses on each bridged NIC - one from the VM and one from the host - shutting the port down all the time.

Comment: You will see two MAC addresses on a bridge, because a bridge is just like a switch. You need a router which can perform forwarding to have all of the MAC addresses rewritten to a single MAC address.

Comment: i know why it's happening. I'd like to remove access from the host machine, and only let the VM access the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bring the interface up, but without associating it with the IP4 protocol.

For Windows, follow the instructions in [VMWare KnowledgeBase article 1020359](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1020359)

1. In the host, open the network adapter settings within Control Panel: Go to Windows > Control Panel and open View network Status and Tasks > Change Adapter settings.
2. Right-click the network adapter and click Properties.
3. Deselect all protocols except VMware Bridge Protocol.
4. Click OK.

For Debian-derivatives (such as Ubuntu), locate the section in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` that looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and replace with:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
  pre-up   ip link set $IFACE up
  pre-down ip link set $IFACE down
```

where `eth0` is the name of the physical network interface (which will have some other name on your computer, e.g. `enp0s25`)